# Please suggest me why my $(window).scrolltop() is not working for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
   if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
    && (lastID != 0)){
        $.ajax({
            url:"main_feed_ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:'feed_id='+lastID,
            cache:false,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('.load-more').show();
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('.load-more').remove();
                $('#postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
  }); 
 });
</script>
```

I have this code for scroll data loading without page refresh. My code is working fine for some few browsers only. Also it is not working on mobile and tablet using google chrome, firefox. Only It is working on Internet Explorer and some chrome browser. So, Please suggest me what I need to change in this code.
Index.php page

```
<div id="postList">
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
require 'dbConfig.php';

// Get records from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_post ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 
5");

if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
 while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $postID = $row["feed_id"];
    $feed_text = $row["feed_text"];
?>
<div class="list-item"><h4><?php echo $feed_text; ?></h4><img 
style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="car.jpg"></div>

<?php } ?>
<div class="load-more" lastID="<?php echo $postID; ?>" style="display: 
none;">
    <img src="loader.gif"/>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

main_feed_ajax.php page

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["feed_id"])){
//Include DB configuration file
$server_access_name="localhost";
$server_access_id="root";
$server_access_pass_code="";
$server_access_batabase_name="inkme"; 

// Create connection
$conn_server_link = mysqli_connect($server_access_name, $server_access_id, 
$server_access_pass_code, $server_access_batabase_name);
if(!$conn_server_link){
echo "!Ops, Unable to connect ";
}
//Get last ID
$lastID = $_POST['feed_id'];

//Limit on data display
$showLimit = 5;

//Get all rows except already displayed
$queryAll = $conn_server_link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM 
user_post WHERE feed_id < ".$lastID." ORDER BY feed_id DESC");
$rowAll = $queryAll->fetch_assoc();
$allNumRows = $rowAll['num_rows'];

//Get rows by limit except already displayed
$query = $conn_server_link->query("SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE feed_id < 
".$lastID." ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT ".$showLimit);
 if($query->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $postID = $row["feed_id"]; 
    $feed_text = $row["feed_text"]; 
    ?>


<div class="list-item"><h4><?php echo $feed_text; ?></h4><img 
style="width:200px; height:200px;" src="car.jpg"></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($allNumRows > $showLimit){ ?>
<div class="load-more" lastID="<?php echo $postID; ?>" style="display: 
none;">
    <img src="loader.gif"/>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="load-more" lastID="0">
   No more feeds
</div>
<?php }
}
else{ ?>
<div class="load-more" lastID="0">
    That's All!
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: We need the full code with HTML

Comment: Somethings may not answer the question but for me its important to say it .. **1ST:** use `data-lastID` attribute instead of just `lastID` .. **2ND** use `!==` instead of `!=` .. **3RD** The attribute return string so use `parseInt($('.load-more').attr('data-lastID'));`

Comment: You suggest that the guilty one here is `scrollTop()`, have you made debugging (with `console.log` for example) that indicates that? Have you compared it to `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` to see what values you get on each browser?

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef: 1ST: use data-lastID attribute instead of just lastID .. 2ND use !== instead of != .. 3RD The attribute return string so use parseInt($('.load-more').attr('data-lastID')); is not working.